# Copy C:\Windows\IME\IMEJP\DICTS fail

Tags: windows

how can we copy C:\Windows\IME\IMEJP\DICTS this file one machine to another machine?
we are unable to copy this file from one machine to another machine

Comment: What are the problem? Do you have an error? Please, explain us what's happening.

Comment: access denied, but am in  admin user

Comment: This is a Windows-only directory. You should have no problems reading from it, but writing is best left to Windows, using the Settings app : Settings > Time & Language > Language. Why do you want to manually do it?

Comment: Japanese Kanji not working in our one Japanese user that's why

Comment: Try to uninstall it from Settings and install back. If it still doesn't work, the problem is not there.

Comment: The problem will be in pasting, not copying ...

Comment: we have already reinstalled but same issue, any other solution is there?

Comment: My Actual problem is Japanese Kanji not working in our one Japanese user, share the troubleshooting if available.